# Apex Test Failures on Installed Packages

Tags: apex, trigger, code-coverage

I'm trying to implement an apex trigger, however, when I try to deploy, I'm getting errors when the Apex tests are running for installed packages we have in the system.

I'm kind of lost here, in the sense that how an installed package fails on their own test classes they created for their own apex trigger?? This is the first time I'm seeing this, and not sure what to do.

Could it be that the App got updated and they forgot to update their test classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the tests for Managed Packages shouldn't be running for a regular deployment so you should confirm which deployment settings you are using. Managed Package tests will typically never work in your org, since they can't know what settings/validation rules etc you have in place, so make sure you are using the right setting:
There are four options when you deploy:

- Default
- Run local tests
- Run all tests
- Run specified tests

Only run all tests will trigger tests in managed packages. You should probably just select default or local depending on the environment

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
Any idea why even when running local tests, it looks like tests for installed packages are running?

Comment: As far as I know that shouldn't happen - is it for all packages/vendors, or just one? If one, I'd reach out to them, but if all, I'd raise a ticket with SFDC